# Python Decrypting with Crypto: first 16 characters are gibberish

Tags: java, python, csv, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt a file that was encrypted in Java using `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`. However, I'm having some trouble completely decrypting the file. I think I'm missing something simple. I am pretty new to encryption, so this is highly probable:

```
import base64
import re

from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

# generate the key
passphrase = "my_secret_passphrase"
key = passphrase[0:16].encode()

# load in the encrypted file as bytes
file_name = "tbd/enc.csv"
with open(file_name, "rb") as in_file:
    encrypted_bytes = in_file.read()

# initialize the cipher
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

# use the cipher to decrypt the bytes
decrypted_bytes = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_bytes)

# write to an out_file
file = re.sub("\.csv", "_decoded.csv", file)
with open(file, "wb") as binary_file:
    binary_file.write(decrypted_bytes)
```

Here's a the first line of text from what I get:

```
M¢p†‘GW§'tÄ%èéired Date,Employees - Id,First,Employees - Middle,Last,Employees - Preferred Name,Job Title,Employees - Marital Status,Employees - Trade Code,...
```

I noticed that the first 16 chars are complete gibberish, so I know I'm close. What could I be missing that is causing the first 16 chars to not be decoded properly? The weird thing is that we are able to decrypt the entire file in java, so we know its something wrong with the python implementation.

Bonus Round: the java code used to encrypt the file (I did not code it nor do I know java):

```
package rpa.ipaengine.bots.cmic.test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class TestFile {
  private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestFile.class);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOGGER.info("running");
    try {
      Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
      encryptedFile("my_secret_passphrase", "/tbd/enc.csv", "tbd/dec.csv");
      decryptedFile("my_secret_passphrase", "/tbd/enc.csv", "tbd/dec.csv");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void encryptedFile(String secretKey, String fileInputPath, String fileOutPath)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
    BadPaddingException {
    try {
      byte[] raw1 = "my_secret_passphrase"
        .getBytes();
      byte[] raw = new String(raw1, 0, 16).getBytes();
      Key skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
      IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParams);
      var fileInput = new File(fileInputPath);
      var inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileInput);
      var inputBytes = new byte[(int) fileInput.length()];
      inputStream.read(inputBytes);
      var outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
      var fileEncryptOut = new File(fileOutPath);
      var outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileEncryptOut);
      outputStream.write(outputBytes);
      inputStream.close();
      outputStream.close();
      System.out.println("File successfully encrypted!");
      System.out.println("New File: " + fileOutPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  public static void decryptedFile(String secretKey, String fileInputPath, String fileOutPath)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
    BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    try {
      byte[] raw1 = "my_secret_passphrase"
        .getBytes();
      byte[] raw = new String(raw1, 0, 16).getBytes();
      Key skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
      IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParams);
      var fileInput = new File(fileInputPath);
      var inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileInput);
      var inputBytes = new byte[(int) fileInput.length()];
      inputStream.read(inputBytes);
      byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
      var fileEncryptOut = new File(fileOutPath);
      var outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileEncryptOut);
      outputStream.write(outputBytes);
      inputStream.close();
      outputStream.close();
      System.out.println("File successfully decrypted!");
      System.out.println("New File: " + fileOutPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: in AES CBC its common to prepend random bytes to the data. Like that identical messages are different when encrypted. Perhaps you are seeing these random bytes and maybe the java implementation is skipping them.

Comment: The first 16 bytes being garbled suggests that you’re using the wrong IV. You certainly shouldn’t be using a random IV when decrypting, you should get it along with the ciphertext. Looking at the Java code it looks like they are using an all zero IV (which is bad). Try using 16 zero bytes as the IV instead of random bytes (sorry, I don’t know how to create this in Python).

Comment: After a little search, I think simply `bytes(16)` will give you what you want to test this.

Comment: **Security warning**: please do not use the Java code as it is **UNSECURE**. It uses a raw string as key and works with a (x0's) fixed initialization vector which makes the complete encryption **vulnerable**. As well there is **no encoding handling** of the key so the code will probably fail when working on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bytes(16)` as matt suggested, I was able to decipher the text completely:

```
import base64
import re

from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

# generate the key
passphrase = "my_secret_passphrase"
key = passphrase[0:16].encode()

# load in the encrypted file as bytes
file_name = "tbd/enc.csv"
with open(file_name, "rb") as in_file:
    encrypted_bytes = in_file.read()

# initialize the cipher
iv = bytes(16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

# use the cipher to decrypt the bytes
decrypted_bytes = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_bytes)

# write to an out_file
file = re.sub("\.csv", "_decoded.csv", file)
with open(file, "wb") as binary_file:
    binary_file.write(decrypted_bytes)
```

First line of file:

```
Employees - Hired Date,Employees - Id,First,Employees - Middle...
```

However Michael provides some valid comments about the Java code used to encrypt the file. I will work with my team to make sure its more secure.